# Memcached is not working with Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I'm trying to use memcached to replace original cache_store.

In development.rb

```
config.consider_all_requests_local  = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :memcached_store
```

In MyController

```
caches_page :index
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

Then, I run memcached -vv to listen the response and refresh the index page. There is no any expected response except.
Very appreciate if any one could help me!

```
<20 send buffer was 9216, now 5592405
<19 server listening (udp)
<19 server listening (udp)
```

But I can find a cache file created in my Public folder and seems ActiveSupport::Cache::Store is working rather than memcached.

Gem file:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'memcached_store'
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
```

And one more thing is curious. Even I set

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

ActiveSupport::Cache::Store still keeps working!!

Comment: Seems I find what happened. This is because I need to specify the directory of cache files manually.

Like

config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/deploy"
config.cache_store = :memcached_store

then I can get the response

Comment: Right on, please consider submitting this as an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create cached page directory

```
config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/deploy"      
config.cache_store = :memcached_store
```

After created cache directory, memcached has replaced cached_store